# Using EksPodOperator giving error passing cluster_role_arn

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-eks, airflow-2.x

*Have been banging my head over the EksPodOperator to run my job through airflow in eks. Airflow version2.4.3*

```
s3_access_arn = 'myarn'

kubernetes_data_prep_task = EksPodOperator(
    task_id="mydatapreptask",
    cluster_name="myclustername",
    namespace="mynamespace",
    pod_name="my_pod_name",
    image="myimagelocation",
    cmds=["sh", "-c", "ls"],
    get_logs=True,
    is_delete_operator_pod=True,
    aws_conn_id="<your_aws_airflow_conn_id>",
    cluster_role_arn=s3_access_arn'
)

kubernetes_data_prep_task
```

**I am getting error in passing cluster_role_arn to the EksPodOperator*

Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/dag_test1.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 408, in apply_defaults
result = func(self, **kwargs, default_args=default_args)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 756, in **init**
f"Invalid arguments were passed to {self.**class**.**name**} (task_id: {task_id}). "
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Invalid arguments were passed to EksPodOperator (task_id: risk_model_data_prep_task). Invalid arguments were:
**kwargs: {'cluster_role_arn': 's3_access_arn'}

I am referring the following link*

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/eks.html#EksPodOperator.template_fields

*Can someone please suggest whats going wrong here. What's the correct way to use EksPodOperator*